# Read file from internal memory: "/sys/class/" and "/dev/" folders

Tags: java, android

I want to know how can I read the value of some files inside the internal memory, but these files aren´t located inside "/data/data/myapp/files" folder, they are located inside "/dev/" and "/sys/class" folders.

```
import...


public class Calentando extends AppCompatActivity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_calentando );





    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private byte[] readFile(String path) {
        File file = new File( "/sys/class/gpio/gpio33/value" );
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( file );
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( fis )) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read( buffer )) != -1) {
                baos.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
           TextView Tempview = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.temperatura );
                Tempview.setText( new String( readFile( path ), Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) ) );
            }
            return baos.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle the exception
            return null;
        }


    }

}
```

Special thanks to @nandsito

Comment: you can achieve it by using the regular File API: `new FileInputStream(new File("/dev"))` but does your app have permission to do so?

Comment: Hello thanks for support, the Tablet is rooted, I have full access to all paths. In the Manifest I added .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions (I think they are only required for files located in external storage). Please, could you provide me an example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your app has root permission, you might be able to access `/dev` and `/sys/class` directories.

You can list a directory content:

```java
new File(path).listFiles();
```

You can read a binary file content:

```java
private byte[] readFile(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle the exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can set a file content in a `TextView` (provided it's a text file):

```java
TextView Tempview;
Tempview = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.temperatura );
Tempview.setText(new String(readFile(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: I tried it, compiles but unfortunatelly, I don´t know how to put the file content into a textView with this code. Please, how to put the file content in a textview?

Comment: @Ana I added an example

Comment: Thanks nandsito, I tried your code but I not had luck. I attached the code and logcat into the end of the first post. The app crashes.

Comment: @Ana if you remove the call to read the file, does it still crash? please post your entire activity

Comment: Hello nandsito, yes the app still crash by removing the read method, so I moved  TextView Tempview = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.temperatura ); into  private byte[] readFile(String path), now the app doesn´t crash but the Textview doesn´t show the content of "value" file .  I am just trying I an empty class, inside the onCreate. I can´t see any error inside Logcat.

Comment: For large files reading it as `byte[]` and then converting it to characters/`String` is a bad idea as you need twice the memory. Why not directly read it using a `InputStreamReader`?

Comment: @Robert indeed, reading a text file with the `Reader` API is better, provided it's known beforehand that a given file is text and the character encoding is also known. However, I tried to make my answer simple

Comment: @Ana hint: try to write the file content in logcat first

Comment: @Robert, I tryed inputStreamReader directly from /data/data/myapp/files folder, if I create a file with  FileOutputStream method then I can read it with inputStreamReader but if I create the file with Android text editor, then InputStreamreader can´t read the file content. The file needs to be in a specific format to can be readed with InputStreamReader?

Comment: @nandsito I don´t understand if you want to see the Logcat or if I should put some more code to write the file content in logcat first (I don´t know how to do this). I Will put new Logcat of your code in the first post and in addition, an InputStreamReader example that didn´t work for me. The content of value is a single bit, a "0" or a "1". Exactly I want to add a "while (value data<1)"... do something with my code. I think that I need to read the file into a String, convert into an int and then I can do all I want to do with it, or this is not the right way?

Comment: @Ana glad I could help :)

Comment: Hello again, I am trying getting a continuous read of the file that I am reading with nandsito´s code, but I can´t find the right way. Please, I´ll like to add an infinite loop to this read method. I need to get a continuous read and put the file content continuosly into the TextView. I tryed with while, do while...but I don´t know where to put it exactly. I tried diferent ways but app crashing. How add a infinite loop properly to this code? Many thanks!

Comment: @Ana it had better be addressed in a question of its own